# foreign key database help needed

Tags: sql, database, subquery

I'm not sure how to title my question, but here is the situation.

I have three SQL tables as follows:

One Lookup table that lists names of adjectives along with a number (primary key value) associated with each adjective.

One Object table that connects to other tables that are outside the situation I need help with.

and One table that connects the object table to the adjectives lookup table. The connecting table has three foreign keys. One that connects to the primary key of the lookup table, and one that connects to the reference key in the Object table.

If I wanted to waste disk space for redundant database entries, I wouldn't be here asking for help, because what I would do is something like this for example:

In the lookup table, say I have the following rows of values:

```
1,"sweet"
2,"bitter"
3,"sour"
```

In the Object table, I have a primary key representing the object, the field for object name, and the reference key to represent all adjectives for the object. For now, we assume it only has two row with these values: Row 1: (Primary key 1,"Raspberry",Reference key value 1), Row 2: (Primary key 2,"Strawberry",Reference key value 4).

Let's say my first step is to make a Raspberry "bitter sweet".
![enter image description here][1]
then in my connecting table (that connects object to adjectives), I have one field a constant value (for the object) and the other field individual values, I put in (1,1) and (1,2) to apply both "bitter" and "sweet" to raspberry.

Let's say I want to make a strawberry "bitter sweet" as well.

then in my connecting table, I put in (4,1) and (4,2) to apply both "bitter" and "sweet" to strawberry.

The problem here is with the first field value in the connecting table because values 1 and 4 mean "bitter sweet". They need to be condensed so I can use either 1 or 4.

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to automate this whole process. Also, I want to be able to prioritize each word. For example, I want to decide which order the adjectives are used.

so far for the example, I have come up with this untested idea:

```
select keytoobject 
from connectingtable 
where keytoobject  in (select keytoobject 
                       from connectingtable 
                       where keytoadjective=1) 
  and keytoobject in (select keytoobject 
                      from connectingtable 
                      where keytoadjective=2) 
group by keytoobject 
having count(*) = 2
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is search the connecting table to see if the exact same adjective set already exists and if it does, then take that key and reuse it instead of make a new key with the same adjectives.

Also, the part that stumps me is that when I take the adjectives, I want to retain their priority as well.

Does anyone have any better idea on how i can tackle this problem?

UPDATE: I added the tables that show what is going on. Since I have less than 10 reputation, I had to post links to the images. I hope I posted them right.

[Database i need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxQrZ.jpg)
[ERD for same database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBydY.jpg)

The word I just realized I was looking for is normalization. I want to normalize the connection table.

In the example (based on the images), I want these words stored in the database:
Bitter sweet raspberry
Bitter sweet strawberry
Super Crazy Sour candy
Crazy sweet sugar (Sorry, I meant to make the bottom left AID value a 4 instead of a 2)
Sweet tooth.

For bitter sweet raspberry and bitter sweet strawberry, I can change it to sweet bitter raspberry and sweet bitter strawberry by swapping the priority values for when CID is 33.

What I want my software to do is this:

First it asks me to enter names of objects. Next it stores the object name and creates a random ID for the object in the object table

Next It asks me to select all the adjectives that apply to the object. Say I choose three of them. Then I give each adjective a priority number so that the computer knows which order they come in for later use. (lets call this object "crazy bitter sweet strawberry")

Once that is done, the software will then create 3 rows of values in the connecting table to apply the set of adjectives to the object. (1 for crazy, 1 for bitter, 1 for sweet)

Say I want to add a new object. It is stored in the objects table along with its new id. Now this time I want to use two adjectives that I used before but I want to avoid having to create extra rows of data if possible. (lets call this "bitter sweet raspberry")

Then for the third object, I add four adjectives, but one matches an adjective in another object. (lets call this "ridiculously super crazy awesome girl")

Then say I want to add 50 more objects with a few adjectives but one is "crazy", and another 50 with a few adjectives but one adjective is "sweet"

The problem here is that my computer will generate an extra 50 rows for the word "crazy" and an extra 50 rows for the word "sweet". Somehow I want the system to reuse the existing 
adjectives if they match up.

Basically the system is a word building application where people can add and remove adjectives to words.

I want to avoid a ridiculously large database if possible. The only way I feel a large database makes sense is if every adjective used was a unique word in all cases.

Something tells me I need another table but I dont know if I'm right.

Oh, and for reference, AID stands for adjective ID number, and CID stands for connecting table ID. Also for the table, One object can have as many adjectives as it would like, and one group of adjectives can apply to as many objects as it would like.

Comment: please simplify your question. Use data examples in tables.

Comment: This is not very clear. 1 and 4 seem to mean raspberry and strawberry, not bitter and sweet. The structure of tables seems to be clear, but the other thing that needs clarification is exactly what you would like as a result set. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I re-edited my post. It is now elaborated and the two links point to the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing your Objects table, you would be better off adding **2** more tables to maintain your adjective "groups".

BUT this assumes that the same groups of adjectives (and priority) are reused regularly. You may find that your original database structure is more suited otherwise, as the extra joins are likely to decrease performance.

I've written it in tsql for SQL Server as you haven't tagged which database you are using.

```
CREATE TABLE [Objects]
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE [Adjectives]
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE [AdjectiveGroup]
(
    GroupID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [AdjectiveGroupDetail]
(
    GroupID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [AdjectiveGroup] (GroupID),
    AID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [Adjectives] ([ID]),
    [Priority] INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (GroupID, AID),
    UNIQUE (GroupID, [Priority])
);

CREATE TABLE [ConnectingTable]
(
    CID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [Objects] ([ID]),
    GroupID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [AdjectiveGroup] (GroupID),
    UNIQUE (GroupID, CID)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Objects] ON;
INSERT INTO [Objects] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Raspberry'), (2, 'Strawberry');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Objects] OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Adjectives] ON;
INSERT INTO [Adjectives] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Sweet'), (2, 'Bitter');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Adjectives] OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [AdjectiveGroup] ON;
INSERT INTO [AdjectiveGroup] (GroupID) VALUES (1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [AdjectiveGroup] OFF;
INSERT INTO [AdjectiveGroupDetail] (GroupID, AID, [Priority]) VALUES (1, 1, 2), (1,2,1);
INSERT INTO [ConnectingTable] (CID, GroupID) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
```

Comment: Your answer arrived after I did the redesign. I am using MySql and I took your thoughts into consideration before you shared them. thanks.